# Operator "|" cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

Tags: c#

Hello everyone so I'm having the problem that its on the title ( Operator `"|"` cannot be applied to operands of type `string` and `string`)

Here is the code that I'm running at the moment

```
if ( (tb_id.Text="") | (tbnome.Text = "") | (tbpreco.Text = "") | (tbquant.Text = "") )
{
        MessageBox.Show("Erro, Voce não inseriu algo"); 
}
```

I really don't know why its happening, I already searched around stackoverflow and other websites and forums but still couldn't see the error.

Comment: `|` is bitwise OR. You need `||`

Comment: @L.B No, it's a non short circuiting OR.  He likely doesn't need it to not short circiut, but it is still a logical operator.

Comment: `tb_id.Text=""` means that you are assigning the value of `""` (empty string) to `tb_id.Text`. Is this intended? Or was `tb_id.Text==""`?

Comment: MSDN says: "`|` operators are predefined for integral types and bool", so it is not defined for `string`

Comment: I should add to my previous comment that `|` is applied to `string` in your case because of your wrong use of `=` instead of `==` (as others have pointed out), but I just wanted to make it clear why you were getting this specific error message.

Answer (score 9):

You want to be using the equality operator `==` not the assignment operator `=`.

The assignment operator returns the value that was assigned to the string, and assigns the value to the string.  The equality operators return a boolean indicating if the two strings are equal.

On a side note, you almost certainly want to be using the short circuiting OR operator `||` instead of the non-short circuiting OR operator `|`, so that if any of the checks pass it doesn't need to bother performing the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this

```
if ( (tb_id.Text=="") || (tbnome.Text == "") || (tbpreco.Text == "") || (tbquant.Text == "") )
{
    MessageBox.Show("Erro, Voce não inseriu algo"); 
}
```

This `==` is the the `equal to` operator.
`=` is an assignment operator.

and for `or` operator `||` not `|`

You might want to read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx

Comment: `|` *is* a logical OR operator.  It simply doesn't short circuit.

Comment: @Servy Thanks I didnt know that. I learn't something new after searching "C# short circuit opearator"

Comment: @Servy you are right that `|` is still a logical operator, but it is only predefined for integral types and bool, and in the case of integral types, it computes the bitwise OR operation on its operands (verbatim from MSDN)

Comment: @LucMorin Correct, so when the OP fixes his code such that it is passing in two boolean types, it's using it as a logical operator, not a bitwise operator.  The use of that operator is not *wrong*.  It doesn't in any way make the program function incorrectly.  It just makes it a tiny tiny bit less performant.  While it's an okay change to make it is not essential, or even particularly important.  The fact that the operator can also be used on integer values doesn't in any way make it incorrect for use on boolean values.

Comment: @Servy agreed. I just wanted to make the difference clear for everyone :-)